# Running the main command in java

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, intellij-idea

I started to learn Java 2 days ago. When I try to run this code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(5*2);
     }
}
```

The terminal says :

```
    12:47:17 PM: Executing task 'Main.main()'...

Executing tasks: [Main.main()] in project C:\Users\Safakhan\AndroidStudioProjects\JavaBasics2


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\Safakhan\AppData\Local\Temp\Main_main__.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:Main.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 298ms
12:47:17 PM: Task execution finished 'Main.main()'.
```

Altough, I tried to delete the

```
build.gradle(:app)
```

this is what my gradle file looks like:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
}
```

But it did not worked. Could you please me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

running fine to me:

```
public class Main{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(5*2);
     }
}
```

output:

```
10
```

are you compiling it right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but. Could you share your dependecies class which is in build.gradle(:app)

Comment: yes. I am trying to understand where did I make mistake

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project is an android project. Thus the gradle errors.

if your aim is to learn java and not android, just changing your IDE to eclipse or Intellij would solve your problem